# Count query for nested document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to count how many Items are available in the sub-document `Recommendations` in the following document.

```
{
   catgoryId: 13,
   Recommendations:
   {
       {ItemId: 135, value= 0.8},
       {ItemId: 136, value= 0.7},
       ....
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation method:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  [
   { 
     $project: {
       categoryId:1,
       count: {$size:"$Recommendations"}
     }
   }
]);
```